# Blazor: Entity Framework session not closed

Tags: .net, entity-framework, blazor

There is a relation between two tables that don't have cascade delete.
If there is a record that has relation to another table, when user wants to delete it, I warn the user that first you should delete related records in the other table. Suppose that user deletes related record in another table, when user want to delete the record that doesn't have a relation, an exception is thrown:

> The association between entity types 'DFile' and 'DGardesh' has been severed, but the relationship is either marked as required or is implicitly required because the foreign key is not nullable. If the dependent/child entity should be deleted when a required relationship is severed, configure the relationship to use cascade deletes. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the key values.

If I refresh the page and again try to delete, it works correctly.

I think it's because Entity Framework session that not closed before delete transaction. What do you think about it?

```
public async Task<bool> DeleteDGardeshAsync(int gId)
    {
        try
        {
            var actualRecord = await _dbContext.DGardesh
                                               .Where(u => u.DGardeshId == gId)
                                               .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
            if (actualRecord != null)
            {
                var removedGardesh = _dbContext.DGardesh.Remove(actualRecord);
                if (removedGardesh != null)
                {
                    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }


public async Task<DDTO> UpdateDAsync(int dId, DDTO dDto)
    {
        DDTO emptyDto = new DDTO();
        try
        {
            var actualRecord = await _dbContext.D
                                                    .Include(u => u.DFiles)
                                                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.DId == dId);
            if (actualRecord != null)
            {
                var record = _mapper.Map(source: dDto, destination: actualRecord);
                var updatedD = _dbContext.D.Update(record);
                await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
                return _mapper.Map<DDTO>(updatedD.Entity);
            }
            else
            {
                emptyDto.DId = -1;
                return emptyDto;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return emptyDto;
        }
    }
```

i call DeleteDGardeshAsync first and then call UpdateDAsync. there is a relation between DFile and DGardesh.

Comment: Please provide the full code example to see how you use DbContext in your page. I believe you might use it incorrectly.

Comment: @DmitriiPolianskii I edit my question and add some code. is it enough?